# Database table structure for allocation by tier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a four-tiered structure of accounts (from top to bottom):

1. Division Level
2. Department Level
3. Sales Rep Level
4. Account Level

Business user needs to be able to allocate/assign units of product at any of the four levels. Assigning 100 units at the Division level allows any deeper level to take from that balance. Assigning 100 units to the Sales Rep level only allows his/her accounts to take from that balance.

I understand how to model this in a 4 table structure, but is that the correct approach here? Should records for all four levels be stored in the same table with a column indicating at which level the units were allocated?

If I place them all in the same table, how do I account for the issue that Division, Department, Sales Rep, and Account codes are 4 different types of codes in four different tables. I would need four FK for each row?

**Edit**

Just for clarity I included an image of, what I think, are my two options. Option 1 results in NULL values for some of the columns. Option 2 is the better option? This is a transactional database, not a data warehouse.

[image]

Comment: Would it make more sense to add an `AllocatedUnits` column to each of the four tables?

Comment: No. The four tables are dimensions of each level. For example, DivisionId,DivisionName..... or... SalesRepId,SalesRepName.... and so on. If I were to put allocations into a single table, I would have NULL values in some of the foreign keys.

Comment: Perhaps we're misunderstanding each other.  What I was referring to is adding `AllocatedUnits` to each of the "structure" tables.  For example `CREATE TABLE Divisions (DivisionId, DivisionName, AllocatedUnits...)` and `CREATE TABLE Departments(DepartmentId, DepartmentName, AllocatedUnits...)` etc.  This makes sense if there's only one kind of allocated unit.  If there are multiple allocation types, then my suggestion would not apply.

Comment: There are multiple types of items and such. However if I do it that way, it sounds like Option 2 in my diagram.

Comment: Yeah, I would tend to agree with Option 2.  You'd include a column for `AllocationType` I presume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Putting this as an answer because the Comments section is too size-limited.)

IMO, neither solution is very future-looking.  What if a new level in the hierarchy is added?  You will have to add a new column for option 1, or a new table for option 2, and then change all your views/queries. And in either case, how will you keep track of which level of the hierarchy has priority over another - hardcoded in your app?  Also, it seems you are only keeping track of the total units allocated at any point in time, but not the total number of potentail units in the pool (I think this is what DMason's question was getting at)?  And it seems you are assuming total potential pools are only assigned at one hierarchal level at a time: what if your company wants the flexibiity to assign to each level (for example, 500 for Division AND 500 on the Account level)?  So I think the modelling options you've presented so far are inflexible from these standpoints.

Wouldn't it make more sense to make a HierarchyLevels table first?  You would have a HierarchyLevelID (identity) column, then a Description column for each level (Division, Department, Sales Rep, and Account, for now), and each would get a Priority, say 1.0-4.0.  Maybe also a column you can store the name of the table that level refers to its reference data (Divisions, Departments, etc.).  Maybe this could even be the internal OBJECT_ID for the relevant table. Then maybe an Allocations table that has the HierarchyLevelID, an ExternalID (DivisionID, DepartmentID, etc., whichever is relevant for the HierarchyLevel), AssignedAllocationUnits (for that level), CurrentlyAllocatedUnits (also for the level).  If there is an overarching data element that binds Allocations, like a ProjectID, you would include that as well (if you have this in HierarchyLevels as well, different projects could get different hierarchy levels and priorities, even!).  Maybe even a calculated column, TotalAllocationUnitsAvailable which does the heavy lifting and calcs the units available in total for that level (not just the explicitly assigned ones) - this could be easily off-loaded to a view, though.  I think this is all the persistent storage you would require.

A challenge in this model is making sure Allocations.ExternalID reflects changes made in the base tables it refers to.  You couldn't do a FK solution here, because that one column holds keys to many different tables.  This could be done with trigger logic from the base tables themselves (I realize the quite possible understatement, lol.).  And then another challenge would be to calc the TotalAllocationUnitsAvailable for any given level at any given time and the transaction handling which would be required to make sure everything is kosher if multiple levels are trying to claim AllocationUnits at the same time.  These issues need to be carefully thought through and implemented.

That being said, I believe a solution as proposed would address the issues I mentioned early on, as well as allow for more flexibility by allowing changes to be made on the data side and not the object side of things.  It is obviously a quick sketch, but I think you know where I'm going.  At the very least, please at least consider the challenges I brought up concerning your current suggestions.  Seems like an interesting project, good luck. =)

Comment: I agree that neither is very future looking which is why I posted here. However the structure has been around the company for 20+ years. Not to say it can't change, but very static for sure. I do have the structure you are talking about (left it out for brevity), but I think you bring up what I was afraid of. That I would need complex logic to dynamically reference different tables, based on their value, in lieu of foreign keys.

Comment: Yes, fair enough, that's what SO is for. =) As far as the base tables having to update the Allocations (or whatever data structure plays the role of it), I actually don't believe it has to be super complex.  Cascade update of key columns, maybe prevent deletion if there are child records.  Some key domain logic to make sure the inserted values exist on the Allocations table.  You may be able to encapsulate it in a couple routines, actually.  Anyway, I think, time and budget willing, do the right modelling now and look like genius in a couple months.  Lol.  Good luck!